# Does adding a foreign key constraint in MySQL cause a table rebuild?

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

I need to alter a large table in order to add a foreign key. Does adding the constraint cause the table to be rebuilt? The referenced table already exists and has an index on the column.

Comment: probably better served over at DBA exchange.

Comment: @lVlint67 not necessarily. Things can be on-topic in more than one place. If something is on topic here, we shouldn't be shoving people around to other sites because it's in topic there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, so long as the column types are identical, as well as the index definitions.

That said, attempting to define a foreign key constraint on two indexes that differ will *fail* and you'll have to alter the tables and/or build/rebuild the indexes manually.